# GLSL using same layout locations with multiple programs

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I can render with multiple programs with the following code:

snippet from near end of main loop in `main.cpp`

```
. . .

glUseProgram( programID1 );

glEnableVertexAttribArray( 0 );
glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertuvbuffer[0] );
glVertexAttribPointer( 0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 20, (void*)0 );
    //only needed XY coordinates for the simple 2D I'm making
glEnableVertexAttribArray( 1 );
glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertuvbuffer[0] );
glVertexAttribPointer( 1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 20, (void*)8 );
    //the third 'UV' coordinate chooses a tile from my 2d texture array
glDrawArrays( GL_TRIANGLES, 0, sizeof( vertuvbuffer0_data ) / 5 );
    //every vertex takes 5 floats, so to get total number I divide by 5
glDisableVertexAttribArray( 0 );
glDisableVertexAttribArray( 1 );

glUseProgram( programID2 );
glEnableVertexAttribArray( 2 );
glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertuvbuffer[1] );
glVertexAttribPointer( 0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 20, (void*)0 );
glEnableVertexAttribArray( 3 );
glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertuvbuffer[1] );
glVertexAttribPointer( 1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 20, (void*)8 );
glDrawArrays( GL_TRIANGLES, 0, sizeof( vertuvbuffer1_data ) / 5 );
...
glDisableVertexAttribArray( 2 );
glDisableVertexAttribArray( 3 );

. . .
```

This is obviously with separate layouts inside the different shaders, what I'm having trouble doing is trying to do this:

```
. . .

glUseProgram( programID1 );

glEnableVertexAttribArray( 0 );
glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertuvbuffer[0] );
glVertexAttribPointer( 0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 20, (void*)0 );
glEnableVertexAttribArray( 1 );
glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertuvbuffer[0] );
glVertexAttribPointer( 1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 20, (void*)8 );
glDrawArrays( GL_TRIANGLES, 0, sizeof( vertuvbuffer0_data ) / 5 );
glDisableVertexAttribArray( 0 );
glDisableVertexAttribArray( 1 );

glUseProgram( programID2 );
glEnableVertexAttribArray( 0 );
glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertuvbuffer[1] );
glVertexAttribPointer( 0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 20, (void*)0 );
glEnableVertexAttribArray( 1 );
glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertuvbuffer[1] );
glVertexAttribPointer( 1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 20, (void*)8 );
glDrawArrays( GL_TRIANGLES, 0, sizeof( vertuvbuffer1_data ) / 5 );
...
glDisableVertexAttribArray( 0 );
glDisableVertexAttribArray( 1 );

. . .
```

The vertex shaders have their respective layout locations.

I'm not sure about how to achieve something similar, if there's no way to do this I would have to write different vertex shaders for every object I want to draw, and I can't imagine that would be the case.

I hope this makes sense, so what can I possibly do at this point?

**EDIT:**
After digging around in my code I decided to rewrite all ~500 lines of actual code that was my main program. It was simply too broken to rescue, mixed random commenting all over the place and weird behaviours didn't work out for me at all. I also opted to render using VAO's instead of straight up VBO's and `glVertexAttribPointer()` since that really only worked for one single VAO in my mess of code. Now I can render multiple VBO's (and several VAO's for that matter) using the same program/vertex shader which is the behaviour I wanted.

Comment: The second sequence should work just fine if you want to draw the same vertices with two different shader programs. Is that what you're doing? Or are you trying to use different vertices? Then you would of course have to make the corresponding `glVertexAttribPointer()` calls.

Comment: (Sorry for the long wait, I had to sleep) Yes drawing different vertices with same shader programs, I thought this was possible. Imagine you have 3 enemies on screen at one time, you would have to write different glVertexAttribPointer() calls for each enemy. This would not only be time consuming, but if each one of them used the same vertex shader and fragment shader you could just pass different information about their location, animation frame etc. I was trying to achieve something similar to this.

Comment: It's completely unclear to me what you're trying to do here, and what the problem is. You say now that you want to use the same shader program with different vertices. But in the code you posted, you switch shader programs, but keep using the same vertices. You may want to revise the question to clarify the problem.

Comment: Whoops again, I'm actually using different vertex buffers. Will edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the following code:

Right before linking the program in the shader creation:

```
glBindAttribLocation( ProgramID, 0, "in_Position" );
//0 being the lication in the shader and
//"in_Position" being the name inside the shader
```

Before "do while" loop:

```
. . .
GLuint vao[2];
glGenVertexArrays( 2, vao );

glBindVertexArray( vao[0] );
GLfloat vbo0_data[] = {
//   Positions
    -1.0f, -1.0f,
     1.0f, -1.0f,
     0.0f,  1.0f
}
GLuint vbo[2];
glGenBuffers( 2, vbo );

glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo[0] );
glBufferData( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof( vbo0_data ), vbo0_data, GL_STATIC_DRAW );

glVertexAttribPointer( 0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)0 );

glEnableVertexAttribArray( 0 );

glBindVertexArray( vao[1] );
GLfloat vbo1_data[] = {
//   Positions
    -1.0f,  1.0f,
     1.0f,  1.0f,
     0.0f, -1.0f
}
glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo[1] );
glBufferData( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof( vbo1_data ), vbo1_data, GL_STATIC_DRAW );

glVertexAttribPointer( 0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)0 );

glEnableVertexAttribArray( 0 );
. . .
```

Inside drawing loop:

```
. . .
glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );

glUseProgram( ProgramID );

glBindVertexArrays( vao[0] );
glDrawArrays( GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3 );

GlBindVertexArrays( vao[1] );
glDrawArrays( GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3 );
. . .
```

The pass-through shaders just writes a half transparent red color that becomes solid red where the triangles intersect,  I know I could have put the VAO's inside a loop for drawing but this was more of a proof of concept to show that it worked for me.
Now comes the tedious part of rewriting the rest of my code...